# Seeking nice approximation methods

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, approximation

Consider the equation $9x^2e^{-x}=1$, Let c be the greatest positive root. Find the greatest positive integer $n$ such that $n<c$.

I was able to do this question by converting it into $9x^2=e^x$, then into $2\ln(3)+2\ln(x)-x=0$, then I defined $f(x)=2\ln(3)+2\ln(x)-x$ and showed that there is a sign change between $f(5)$ and $f(6)$ by using rough decimal approximations that I happened to know. This leads to the answer of $n=5$. I should note that a previous part of the question had me sketch the graph $y=9x^2e^{-x}$ for some intuition.

My problem is the fact that I had to use knowledge of decimal expansions which is not a favourable method for me. I'm curious to see if anyone knows of more efficient or elegant methods to answer this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sooner or later, you will learn that the only explicit solutions of the equation are given in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) which is very useful and extensively used in many areas. Just by curiosity, type *Lambert* on the eseach bar of the site and you will notice $4047$ entries.

The root you are looking for is given by
$$x=-2 W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{6}\right)$$ which you can approximate using the expansion given in the linked page

$$W_{-1}(t)=L_1-L_2+\frac{L_2}{L_1}+\frac{L_2(L_2-2)}{2L_1^2}+\frac{L_2(6-9L_2+2L_2^2)}{6L_1^3}+\cdots$$ where where $L_1=\log(-t)$ and $L_2=\log(-L_1)$.

Using the truncated expansion, this would give $x \sim 5.70664$ while the exact solution is $x=5.66630$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've come across the Lambert function on youtube but I haven't looked into it much.